# Photoshop scripting get control position

Tags: javascript, vbscript, photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-sdk

I would like to get a position of lets say a brush tool button inside photoshop.
Is that possible with Photoshop scripting?
Is it possible getting the value of a certain edit box (eg. brush size)?

[image]

Can it be done similar to this:

```
'PsJavaScriptExecutionMode Enums
Const psNeverShowDebugger = 1, psDebuggerOnError = 2, psBeforeRunning = 3

Dim appRef
Set appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")

Dim pos
pos = appRef.ControlPosition("paintbrushTool") //this is made up
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two separate things:

1. The value of a certain edit box (eg. brush size)
2. The position of the Paint Brush tool itself.  This is a UI question.

It's my understanding that for the first question, you're better off creating a brush present and scripting something to select that preset than you are trying to programmatically change the brush size, but I could be wrong.

[This thread](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4957019#4957019) from the Adobe forums sounds relevant to what you're trying to accomplish, in regards to brushes and windows:

> • get the current values
>
> • adjust the value of the one property you want to change, like
>   rotation
>
> • set the values

Unfortunately I don't think the original poster was satisfied with the answers.

You might be better off making your own panel than trying to script the existing brush panel, but I could be wrong.

According to an old JavaScript Tools Guide for Adobe CC I found there is a ScriptUIBrush object:

> ScriptUIBrush object A helper object that encapsulates the qualities
>   of a brush used to paint fill into a path in a control. Create with
>   the newBrush() method of the ScriptUIGraphics object.

I hope this helps!

Comment: "You might be better off making your own panel than trying to script the existing brush panel, but I could be wrong." I totally agree. Making your own panel is fairly trivial and gives you 100% certainty of where you controls are.